# How can I get Multiplication from selected two numbers from drop down using java script and html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below code displays two dropdowns for height and width.

```
<p>width</p>
<select><?php
    for ($i=600; $i<=2600; $i+=100)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?></select>

<p><br>height</p>
<select><?php
    for ($i=600; $i<=2600; $i+=100)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
?></select>
```

As a example if someone selects 600 and 600 how can I display the Multiplication of those numbers below.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have no idea @Sterling Archer

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Do you want to reload the page? Or do you want the answer to instantly appear?

Comment: Break down your problem into parts. First figure out how you would get access to the two numbers. Then how you would do the math in javascript. Then how you would display the numbers. If you tackle it one bit at the time, rather than throwing up your arms and surrendering, or hoping someone will do it for you, I promise you can solve it.

Comment: If it can appear when i select its good for now its OK with refresh @Jay Balanchard

Comment: @Hemal look up JavaScript "event listeners". Use one on each of your `<select>` elements. That should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok not sure when you want to do the multiplication so I would do it on load and when ever you select a drop down option.
Add the following **id's** and **onchange** events to your select options:

First select option.

```
<select id="width" onchange="calculateTotal()">
```

Second select option.

```
<select id="height" onchange="calculateTotal()">
```

Add the following javascript on top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateTotal() {
    var value0 = document.getElementById('width').value;
    var value1 = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var total = value0 * value1;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total is:" + total;  
}
window.onload = calculateTotal;
</script>
```

Then add this paragraph after the options to display the total:

```
<p id="total"></p>
```

NB: You might want to check if the values are empty or null before multiplying even thought it is not necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do like this

Provide id to the both select lists

```
       $("#select1id,#select2id ").change(function(){
                Var width =  $("#select1id option:selected").Val();

                 Var height =  $("#select2id option:selected").Val();
                 Var result = width*height;
                 $("#result").text(result); // Write one <p id="result"> </p>

           });
```